# Cross-reference hyperlinks in glossaries?

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, glossaries

Is is possible to include a webpage or even biblatex reference in the `see=` option of a `glossries` entry? I tried the following. (Crucial are the two comments and the line below them.)

```
% gloss.tex
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym[
  description={Popular Q\&A community specifically dealing with LaTeX},
  %see={\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{their webpage}}
  %see={\cite{texse}}
  see={http://tex.stackexchange.com/}
]{texse}{tex.se}{tex.stackexchange}

\begin{document}
Let me tell you about \gls{texse}.
\printglossaries
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{gloss}
\end{document}
```

Here is the bibliography for your reference.

```
%gloss.bib
@misc{texse,
  author = "The Community",
  title = "LaTex Stack Exchange",
  month = "January",
  year = 2014,
  url = "http://tex.stackexchange.com/"
}
```

It results in nothing to `see`. (It is not cut out by `standalone` cropping, there really is nothing there.)

[image: nothing to see here]

Using one of the two commented alternatives instead even results in an error.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\cite  ->\begingroup \let \NAT@ctype 
                                     \z@ \NAT@partrue \NAT@swatrue \@ifstar ...
l.6 ...at[\seename ]{\protect \cite  {texse}}{Z}}}
```

Can cross-references to the web or the bibliography be specified with `glossaries`?

Comment: A key to another entry is expected there. There is no reason you cannot include such links in the description itself, though. But `see=` really expects a specifically *internal* reference, as far as I understand it.

Comment: `see` just seems to be the exact appropriate place for a reference, so I first look for a solution to include also an external reference there. If this is not possible, moving the link to the description would indeed be the fallback solution.

Answer (score 3):

As has been noted in the comments (and in chapter 4 of [the user guide](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:newglosentry)) the `see` key is only for internal cross-references to other glossary entries.

**Under the Hood**

When you use `see={xr-label}` you are effectively using

```
\glsadd[format={glsseeformat[\seename]{xr-label}}]{label}
```

(where `xr-label` is the cross-referenced label). For example, suppose you define:

```
\newglossaryentry{sample1}{name={sample1},description={first example}}
\newglossaryentry{sample2}{name={sample2},description={second example},see={sample1}}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
\newglossaryentry{sample1}{name={sample1},description={first example}}
\newglossaryentry{sample2}{name={sample2},description={second example}}

\glsadd[format={glsseeformat[\seename]{sample1}}]{sample2}
```

So in the location list for `sample2` in your glossary you get:

```
\glsseeformat[\seename]{sample1}{Z}
```

`Z` is an artificial page number since `makeindex` always requires a location, so `\glsseeformat` is defined to ignore that argument. The `\glsseeformat` command requires its first mandatory argument to be a comma-separated list of entry labels. (In this case it's a list of size one.) The `see` key in `\newglossaryentry` (and `\newacronym`) is provided as a convenient shortcut for this purpose. If you want something else, you need to use `\glsadd` explicitly. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[description]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym[
  description={Popular Q\&A community specifically dealing with
LaTeX}]{texse}{tex.se}{tex.stackexchange}

\newcommand{\urlsee}[2]{\emph{\seename} \url{#1}}

\glsadd[format=urlsee{http://www.stackexchange.com/}]{texse}

\begin{document}
Let me tell you about \gls{texse}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]

**Note:** This will work for URLs like the one in the example, but you're likely to have problems with addresses that contain special characters (such as `~` or `%`).

**Edit:**

You can use a similar method for citations:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{gloss.bib}
@misc{texse,
  author = "The Community",
  title = "LaTex Stack Exchange",
  month = "January",
  year = 2014,
  url = "http://tex.stackexchange.com/"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[description]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym[
  description={Popular Q\&A community specifically dealing with
LaTeX}]{texse}{tex.se}{tex.stackexchange}

\newcommand{\citesee}[2]{\emph{\seename} \cite{texse}}

\glsadd[format=citesee{texse}]{texse}

\begin{document}
Let me tell you about \gls{texse}.

\printglossaries

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{gloss}
\end{document}
```

If you want to mix both `\cite` and `\url` it will look rather odd if you do both

```
\glsadd[format=urlsee{http://tex.stackexchange.com}]{texse}
\glsadd[format=citesee{texse}]{texse}
```

as then you'll get

```
\emph{see} \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}, \emph{see} \cite{texse}
```

in the location list. The alternative is to do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{gloss.bib}
@misc{texse,
  author = "The Community",
  title = "{\TeX}\ on Stack Exchange",
  month = "January",
  year = 2014,
  url = "http://tex.stackexchange.com/"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[description]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym[
  description={Popular Q\&A community specifically dealing with
LaTeX}]{texse}{tex.se}{tex.stackexchange}

\providecommand{\see}[2]{\emph{\seename} #1}

\glsadd[format=see{\string\cite{texse}, \string\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}}]{texse}

\begin{document}
Let me tell you about \gls{texse}.

\printglossaries

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{gloss}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]